# Access SQL COUNT records grouped by two fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by, inner-join

Table1

```
ID1  LETTER
1    A
1    B
2    R
2    S
2    T
3    Z
```

Table2

```
ID1  NAME
1    Pete
2    Andy
3    Mary
```

SQL command in Access:

```
SELECT name, letter
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID1 = table2.ID1
GROUP BY name, letter
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Ultimately, I created a query that produces this:

```
NAME  LETTER
Pete  A
Pete  B
Andy  R
Andy  S
Andy  T
Mary  Z
```

I'm trying to produce output that gives only those individuals along with the associated letter who have more than two entries attributed to them. So something like the following:

```
NAME  FIELD
Andy  R
Andy  S
Andy  T
```

But when I group by name AND field, the count is only going to be 1 for each unique combination, so the SQL outputs no entries when run.

If I try to GROUP BY name solely, access yells as me that my query doesn't include the specified expression 'letter' as part of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to do the aggregation on just the id in the first table and join that it:

```
SELECT table2.name, table1.letter
FROM (table1 INNER JOIN
      table2 
      ON table1.ID1 = t2.ID1
     ) INNER JOIN
     (SELECT id1, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY id1
     ) as t1cnt
     ON t1.ID1 = t1cnt.ID1
WHERE t1cnt.cnt > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE and group it first and then join to get the letter values as follows:

```
with CTE(name, ID1)
as(
SELECT name, table1.ID1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID1 = table2.ID1       GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT( * ) > 2
)
SELECT name, letter
FROM cte
INNER JOIN table2 ON cte.ID1 = table2.ID1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select name, letter
from table1
  inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
  inner join
    (select id
     from table1
     group by id
     having count(*) > 2) as t1 on t1.id = table1.id;
```